# External library not working in release apk android

Tags: android

I am migrating my android project eclipse to an android studio. In the project, I used the JTDS library to connect Databases. The problem is that it's working fine with debug Apkbut when I created release Apk, I got the following error.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.BlobImpl
```

So after some RND, I guess there is a problem in the release Apk that is not able to include jtds jar file in Apk. Please suggest to me.

here is some code:

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig {
            storeFile file('F:\\codebase\\android')
            storePassword var3
            keyAlias = var4
            keyPassword var5
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\jtds-1.2.5.jar')
    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
}
```

This function is not working in release Apk

```
  public static Statement connectionOpen() {
        try {
            // Establish the connection.
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionData.setExceptionData(e.getMessage(), "connectionOpen");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stmt;
    }
```

Logcat Error

```
2019-12-24 15:11:45.524 7770-7890/com.dm.rcl_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.m.app, PID: 7770
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.BlobImpl
        at c.a.a.a.l0.a(:75)
        at c.a.a.a.l0.<clinit>(:87)
        at c.a.a.a.l0.a(:117)
        at c.a.a.a.h.a(:1500)
        at c.a.a.a.n0.M(:3219)
        at c.a.a.a.n0.w(:2282)
        at c.a.a.a.n0.a(:610)
        at c.a.a.a.h.<init>(:345)
        at c.a.a.a.m.connect(:187)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:236)
        at b.a.d.g.b(:41)
        at com.dm._app.Syncronization$d.a(:225)
        at com.dm._app.Syncronization$d.doInBackground(:192)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
2019-12-24 15:11:45.576 4844-4923/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'a694dba processing Data (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-12-24 15:11:45.576 4844-4923/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f996a44 com.dm.rcl_app/com.dm.Syncronization (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** 
Add this line in proguard-rules.pro

`-keep net.sourceforge.jtds.**`

**END Update**

If if only occurs in release mode, you have not configured proguard rules properly.
Take a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268898/android-signed-apk-net-sourceforge-jtds-errors).

Adding this line in proguard-rules.pro should solve the issue

`-dontwarn net.sourceforge.jtds.**`

Comment: you need to add -keep public class net.sourceforge.jtds.** instead of -keep net.sourceforge.jtds.**

Comment: @User1235 it was an simple copy-paste mistake

Comment: @User1235 if it solves the problem, you should accept the answer too!